# How to add an anchor tag in the middle of a <p> element when using document.createElement("p")

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `document.createElement("p")` to dynamically create elements. I need to create an element `<p></p>` with an anchor tag in the middle of it so it creates a link word.

I want to be able to inject the following html using Javascript using `document.createElement("p")`:

```
<p> This is a <a href="google.com">link</a> to google</p>
```

The word link should be an anchor tag surrounded by text from the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML`

```
let p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "This is a <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> to google";

// append it
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: You are a champion. Sometimes when you are too deep into coding, you cant see the obvious and tend to look for overly complicated solutions. I've been trying for 2hrs now to nest elements via appendChild, when the answer was actually just to take a step back. Thnx!

Comment: Hope this would help :)